# Bing Image Search v5.0 returns error

Tags: objective-c, azure-cognitive-services

As of today (September 13, 2017) did Bing Image Search v 5.0 change their backend API?

Using [this console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f/console), adding the header "Content-Type" with a value of "multipart/form-data" gives a response with expected values.

However, when called from my iOS app with the exact same parameters and headers, I receive an error response of "RequestParameterInvalidValue;
            message = "Parameter has invalid value.";
            parameter = imgurl;"

The following code worked as of yesterday:

```
   NSString* path = @"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search";
    NSString* skip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skip=%li", (long)searchOffset];
    NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"q=%@", searchQuery];
    NSArray* array = @[
                   // Request parameters
                   @"entities=true",
                   @"count=50",
                   skip,
                   @"safeSearch=Strict",
                   queryString

                  ];

NSString* string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", string];

NSLog(@"%@", path);

NSMutableURLRequest* _request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// Request headers
[_request setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[_request setValue:accessKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"];
// Request body
[_request setHTTPBody:[path dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I can remove the Content-Type header from the code in Test and get a working response, but this worked yesterday on our Production app. Is there a workaround to get my production code working again without having to resubmit the App for approval?

Comment: I actually experienced the same behavior yesterday! My tests passed and suddenly this one started to fail with the exact same error...

Comment: Seems like the content-type header is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix in deployment now that should fix issue with POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this error right now. Tried to debug it and this is what my dump returned:

```
HTTP_Request2_Response {#460 ▼
#version: "1.1"
#code: 400
#reasonPhrase: "Bad Request"
#effectiveUrl: 
"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=cats"
#headers: array:16 [▼
"cache-control" => "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
"pragma" => "no-cache"
"content-length" => "169"
"content-type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8"
"expires" => "-1"
"vary" => "Accept-Encoding"
"server" => "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
"p3p" => "CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND""
"bingapis-traceid" => "18AAD6F029D1439EB653971FBD07B6EF"
"x-msedge-clientid" => "260206484A6764FE375C0CB54B826518"
"x-msapi-userstate" => "d3dd"
"x-msedge-ref" => "Ref A: 18AAD6F029D1439EB653971FBD07B6EF Ref B: 
SG2EDGE0713 Ref C: 2017-09-14T07:12:07Z"
"apim-request-id" => "9de68803-fee7-4a56-aa0e-f00e2b43929b"
"strict-transport-security" => "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; 
preload"
"x-content-type-options" => "nosniff"
"date" => "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 07:12:06 GMT"
]
#cookies: []
#lastHeader: "date"
#body: "{"_type": "ErrorResponse", "instrumentation": {}, "errors": 
[{"code": "RequestParameterInvalidValue", "message": "Parameter has 
invalid value.", "parameter": "i ▶"
#bodyEncoded: true
```

I thought there was something wrong with my code but then I saw your thread here and concluded it was an error on Bing/Azure's end.

Answer (score 0):

The following `curl` works. However, yesterday I completely redid my Microsoft cognitive keys in all categories because they became broken. I thought the keys probably broke months ago but maybe it was just yesterday. I did not have to change any parameters in any of my many test files.

```
curl "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=cats" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <My Bing Search API Key 1>"
```